# Is it possible to install an Nvidia driver on VM?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualization

I have a 1050Ti on my laptop, and I am trying to run some AI software (called StyleFlow), available only on Linux. the software depends on installing Nvidia drivers. Due to my workflow (for now), I can't dual boot, boot from drive or format the laptop.
I am running the latest Ubuntu on VMPlayer (Windows 10 is host), I can't find the driver in software manager. (see image attached).
attempts to install the .run driver , both the one downloaded from NVidia website and the one cited on Ubuntu website, give errors.
screenshots are all attached.(couldn't attach build log as it is too long)

Is it even ***possible*** to install an Nvidia driver on VM?

Comment: *Usually* no. Virtual machines are generally presented with a generic set of devices by the VM engine, not the actual hardware of the host. What you would need to do is dedicate the video card to the VM with a pass-through, but most virtualization engines will not do this for built-in hardware.

Comment: You have to search for PCI passthrough - like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF .